# Alfresco Workflow: No valid SecureContext in Activiti bpmn script for timer event

Tags: alfresco, activiti, bpmn

I have a workflow which has an embedded script that does some messing around with permissions, which runs when the workflow finishes. I have the runas property set to "admin" for the task and for the most part this works, IF the overall action is triggered by a user action(completed by the assignee or canceled by the initiator ). But when it's triggered by a boundaryEvent timer I get the following error.

> 2017-02-28 10:44:04,645 ERROR [impl.jobexecutor.ExecuteJobsRunnable]
>   [pool-17-thread-1] exception during job execution: 012814135 Found 1
>   integrity violations: A valid SecureContext was not provided in the
>   RequestContext

Note it's the exact same piece of code running each time.

It's the first executionListener defined that's generating the exception. Here's my process definition:

```
    <process id="GrantPermi" name="Grant Permissions" isExecutable="true">
    <extensionElements>
        <activiti:executionListener event="end" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.listener.ScriptExecutionListener">
            <activiti:field name="runAs">
                <activiti:string><![CDATA[admin]]></activiti:string>
            </activiti:field>
            <activiti:field name="script">
                <activiti:string><![CDATA[
                    logger.log("process extensionElements end : " + person.properties.userName);
                    if( execution.getVariable('processextensionElementsend') != true )
                    {
                        var groupName = execution.getVariable('GroupName');
                        for (var i in bpm_package.children)
                        {
                            bpm_package.children[i].removePermission("SiteConsumer", "GROUP_" + groupName );
                        }                           
                        groups.getGroup(groupName).deleteGroup();
                    }
                    execution.setVariable('processextensionElementsend',true);                      
                ]]></activiti:string>
            </activiti:field>
        </activiti:executionListener>
    </extensionElements>
    <startEvent id="alfrescoStartevent1" name="Alfresco start" activiti:formKey="DACGPWF:submitGrantPermiTask"></startEvent>

    <scriptTask id="scripttask1" name="Script Task" scriptFormat="js" activiti:autoStoreVariables="false">
        <script><![CDATA[               
            if(DACGPWF_expires == null)
            {                   
                var dat = new Date();
                dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + 7);
                execution.setVariable('DACGPWF_expires', dat.toISOString());
            }
        ]]></script>
    </scriptTask>
    <userTask id="alfrescoUsertask1" name="Temporary Permissions" activiti:assignee="${bpm_assignee.properties.userName}" activiti:formKey="DACGPWF:assigneeTask">
        <extensionElements>
            <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
                <activiti:field name="runAs">
                    <activiti:string><![CDATA[admin]]></activiti:string>
                </activiti:field>
                <activiti:field name="script">
                    <activiti:string><![CDATA[logger.log("alfrescoUsertask1 create : " + person.properties.userName + " Expires " + DACGPWF_expires );
                        var groupName = "GrantPermi" + new Date().getTime();
                        var group = people.createGroup(groupName);
                        var user = people.getPerson(bpm_assignee.properties.userName);
                        people.addAuthority(group, user);
                        for (var i in bpm_package.children)
                        {                                   
                            bpm_package.children[i].setPermission("SiteConsumer", "GROUP_" + groupName);                                    
                        }
                        execution.setVariable('GroupName',groupName);]]></activiti:string>
                </activiti:field>
            </activiti:taskListener>
        </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <boundaryEvent id="boundarytimer1" name="Timer" attachedToRef="alfrescoUsertask1" cancelActivity="true">
        <timerEventDefinition>
            <timeDate>${DACGPWF_expires}</timeDate>
        </timerEventDefinition>
    </boundaryEvent>
    <endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>

    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="alfrescoUsertask1" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow3" sourceRef="boundarytimer1" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow4" sourceRef="scripttask1" targetRef="alfrescoUsertask1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow5" sourceRef="alfrescoStartevent1" targetRef="scripttask1"></sequenceFlow>
</process>
```

Here is a Java class I call instead of the script, but I get the same behaviour: Works when a user invokes it, fails when called by a timer.

```
public class RemoveGroup implements ExecutionListener{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public void notify(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception
{
    final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = getServiceRegistry();        
    if(execution.getVariable("processextensionElementsend") == null)
    {
        String shortName = execution.getVariable("GroupName").toString();
        final String fullName = serviceRegistry.getAuthorityService().getName(AuthorityType.GROUP, shortName);

        //AuthenticationUtil.setFullyAuthenticatedUser(AuthenticationUtil.SYSTEM_USER_NAME);
        AuthenticationUtil.setAdminUserAsFullyAuthenticatedUser();
        serviceRegistry.getAuthorityService().deleteAuthority(fullName);
        /*
        AuthenticationUtil.runAs(new AuthenticationUtil.RunAsWork<Void>()
        {
            public Void doWork() throws Exception
            {
                serviceRegistry.getAuthorityService().deleteAuthority(fullName);
                return null;
            }
        }, AuthenticationUtil.getSystemUserName());
        */
    }
    execution.setVariable("processextensionElementsend", true);
}
protected ServiceRegistry getServiceRegistry()
{
    ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl config = Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration();
    if(config != null)
    {
        // Fetch the registry that is injected in the activiti spring-configuration
        ServiceRegistry registry = (ServiceRegistry)config.getBeans().get(ActivitiConstants.SERVICE_REGISTRY_BEAN_KEY);
        if(registry == null)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Service-registry not present in ProcessEngineConfiguration beans, expected ServiceRegistry with key" + ActivitiConstants.SERVICE_REGISTRY_BEAN_KEY);
        }
        return registry;
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("No ProcessEngineCOnfiguration found in active context");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

We had same issue sometimes back and we moved our custom script to the Java delegates. It is better to use java delegates to do some complex logics and you should be able to `runAs` in the java deleagates also.

```
AuthenticationUtil.runAs(new AuthenticationUtil.RunAsWork<Void>()
                        {
                            public Void doWork() throws Exception
                            {
                               ......
                               ........
                               return null;
                            }
                        }, AuthenticationUtil.getSystemUserName());
```

Refer the below link.
​https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/workflow/run-activiti-script-system-alfresco-50-03242015-1058

Can you please try slightly different method as mentioned below ?

```
AuthenticationUtil.runAsSystem(new RunAsWork<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void doWork() throws Exception
    {
       ....
       ...
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to work either. I just tried and get the same pattern of behaviour. User initiated actions work fine, but those coming from a timer fail with the valid SecureContext error.  I tried both using `AuthenticationUtil.runAs` as you suggest and also `AuthenticationUtil.setFullyAuthenticatedUser(AuthenticationUtil.SYSTEM_USER_NAME);`

Comment: Will you able to share your code to check.. I have used AuthenticationUtil in lot of places in the java delegates and all are working fine.

Comment: I put it in my original post. I too have used AuthenticationU‌til plenty and it's never given me this kind of trouble.

Comment: Can you please try like ? `AuthenticationUtil.runAsSystem...` I updated the answer.

Comment: Let me try to reproduce this on my local instance and wil try to help you.